# R Titanic dataset practice -- trying to find ratio survived

Tags: r, ggplot2, dplyr

I'm practicing using the Titanic dataset. Here is the code I have so far. I'll also share the data using dput here in case there are multiple versions of the Titanic dataset floating around.

```
structure(list(Class = c("1st", "2nd", "3rd", "Crew", "1st", 
"2nd", "3rd", "Crew", "1st", "2nd", "3rd", "Crew", "1st", "2nd", 
"3rd", "Crew", "1st", "2nd", "3rd", "Crew", "1st", "2nd", "3rd", 
"Crew", "1st", "2nd", "3rd", "Crew", "1st", "2nd", "3rd", "Crew"
), Sex = c("Male", "Male", "Male", "Male", "Female", "Female", 
"Female", "Female", "Male", "Male", "Male", "Male", "Female", 
"Female", "Female", "Female", "Male", "Male", "Male", "Male", 
"Female", "Female", "Female", "Female", "Male", "Male", "Male", 
"Male", "Female", "Female", "Female", "Female"), Age = c("Child", 
"Child", "Child", "Child", "Child", "Child", "Child", "Child", 
"Adult", "Adult", "Adult", "Adult", "Adult", "Adult", "Adult", 
"Adult", "Child", "Child", "Child", "Child", "Child", "Child", 
"Child", "Child", "Adult", "Adult", "Adult", "Adult", "Adult", 
"Adult", "Adult", "Adult"), Survived = c("No", "No", "No", "No", 
"No", "No", "No", "No", "No", "No", "No", "No", "No", "No", "No", 
"No", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", 
"Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes"), n = c(0, 
0, 35, 0, 0, 0, 17, 0, 118, 154, 387, 670, 4, 13, 89, 3, 5, 11, 
13, 0, 1, 13, 14, 0, 57, 14, 75, 192, 140, 80, 76, 20)), row.names = c(NA, 
-32L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))

library(tibble)
library(ggplot2)

Titanic <- Titanic

Titanic <- as.tibble(Titanic)

ggplot(Titanic, aes(x = Survived, y = n, fill = Class)) +
  geom_col(position = "dodge")

grouped_t <- Titanic %>%
  group_by(Class, Survived) %>%
  mutate(ratio_survived_each_class = n / sum(n))

ggplot(grouped_t, aes(x = Survived, y = ratio_survived_each_class, fill = Class)) +
  geom_col(position = "dodge")
```

[image]

[image]

The first graph I think is interesting because it shows the difference in survival for different passenger classes. I'm trying to figure out how to graph the ratio of survived / did not survive side-by-side. I had thought that I could just mutate a new column that is n / sum(n) after grouping by the two grouping variables, Class and Survived ... but then I end up with a graph that doesn't make sense -- about 100% of the crew survived and about 88% of the crew did not survive... it should add up to 100% right?

The other thing I'm trying to make sense of is reversing the order of x-axis factors in ggplot2. I've been looking through StackOverflow for answers but nothing is working for me. Take this scatterplot. I want Crew on the left.

ggplot(Titanic, aes(x = Class, y = n, color = Survived)) +
geom_point()

[image]

```
+ scale_x_reverse()
```

doesn't work because it's not numerical (I think)

```
  scale_x_continuous(trans = "reverse")
```

doesn't work (I don't know why)

```
  scale_x_discrete(limits = rev(levels(Titanic$Class)))
```

also doesn't work (I don't know why)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to aggregate your results first:

```
grouped_t <- 
  Titanic %>%
  group_by(Survived, Class) %>%  # use Survived first
  summarise(sum_n = sum(n)) %>%  # make helper to aggregate group n's
  mutate(ratio_survived_each_class = sum_n/sum(sum_n))
```

Now the plot should work as suggested by you:

```
ggplot(grouped_t, aes(x = Survived, y = ratio_survived_each_class, fill = Class)) +
  geom_col(position = "dodge")
```

Comment: That makes sense -- do the summarise first and then come up with a ratio... thanks for the help.   But why Survived first -- how does the order of group_by matter?

Comment: In general you are right, but in this case we need `sum(sum_n)` , otherwise we would sum over `Class`

Comment: You can also change `position = "dodge"` to `position = "fill"` for a stacked bar plot.

Comment: Oh I see and then we would end up with a sum of 4 because there are 4 passenger classes and not a sum of 2 for the Survived/Did Not Survive distinction

Answer (score 2):

For your question about ordering the x-axis, you can convert to an ordered factor.

```
Titanic %>% 
  mutate(Class = factor(Class, ordered = TRUE, levels = c("Crew", "1st", "2nd", "3rd"))) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = Class, y = n, color = Survived)) + 
  geom_point()
```

Comment: This is also helpful thank you

Your code with the mutate works well -- why doesn't this code also work? It looks the same to me? 
 
Titanic$Class < as.factor(Titanic$Class, ordered = TRUE, levels = c("Crew", "1st", "2nd", "3rd"))

This as.factor code I just created doesn't work but I don't know why

Would you say scale_x_reverse and scale_x_discrete doesn't work on character types?

Comment: Try `Titanic$Class <- factor(Titanic$Class, ordered = TRUE, levels = c("Crew", "1st", "2nd", "3rd")) `.

Comment: Oh so factor by itself has these additonal but as.factor does not

Comment: `as.factor` does not take any arguments other than the vector.

Answer (score 1):

Adding onto @holzben's solution, you can opt to create a stacked barplot using `position = "fill"`. I also included `geom_text` which adds the percentages to each class in the stack. Perhaps this might be a better way to visualize instead of using `dodge`.

```r
grouped_t <- structure(list(Class = c("1st", "2nd", "3rd", "Crew", "1st", 
"2nd", "3rd", "Crew", "1st", "2nd", "3rd", "Crew", "1st", "2nd", 
"3rd", "Crew", "1st", "2nd", "3rd", "Crew", "1st", "2nd", "3rd", 
"Crew", "1st", "2nd", "3rd", "Crew", "1st", "2nd", "3rd", "Crew"
), Sex = c("Male", "Male", "Male", "Male", "Female", "Female", 
"Female", "Female", "Male", "Male", "Male", "Male", "Female", 
"Female", "Female", "Female", "Male", "Male", "Male", "Male", 
"Female", "Female", "Female", "Female", "Male", "Male", "Male", 
"Male", "Female", "Female", "Female", "Female"), Age = c("Child", 
"Child", "Child", "Child", "Child", "Child", "Child", "Child", 
"Adult", "Adult", "Adult", "Adult", "Adult", "Adult", "Adult", 
"Adult", "Child", "Child", "Child", "Child", "Child", "Child", 
"Child", "Child", "Adult", "Adult", "Adult", "Adult", "Adult", 
"Adult", "Adult", "Adult"), Survived = c("No", "No", "No", "No", 
"No", "No", "No", "No", "No", "No", "No", "No", "No", "No", "No", 
"No", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", 
"Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes"), n = c(0, 
0, 35, 0, 0, 0, 17, 0, 118, 154, 387, 670, 4, 13, 89, 3, 5, 11, 
13, 0, 1, 13, 14, 0, 57, 14, 75, 192, 140, 80, 76, 20)), row.names = c(NA, 
-32L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))

library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)

  grouped_t <- grouped_t %>%
  group_by(Survived, Class) %>%  # use Survived first
  summarise(sum_n = sum(n)) %>%  # make helper to aggregate group n's
  mutate(ratio_survived_each_class = sum_n/sum(sum_n)) 
  
ggplot(grouped_t, aes(x = Survived, y = ratio_survived_each_class, fill = Class)) +
  geom_col(position = "fill") +
  geom_text(aes(label = paste(round(ratio_survived_each_class * 100), "%"), y = ratio_survived_each_class), position = position_fill(vjust = 0.5))
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2020-11-12 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>